# Piv Card Authentication

Tags: qgis, authentication, certification, key-value-store, pkinfo

My company issues piv cards for authenticating with various sites and systems.  We have data we would like to add to QGIS, but they are protected behind our pvliv card authentication. Typically. I can go to the site,  be promoted for my piv pin, then I'm in.

I'm trying to figure out how I can set up the authentication to work in QGIS.

I have what I believe is the certificate bundle, but when I go to add it under the pki bundle,  it doesn't let me.

Maybe I need something different?